# Regex issue with PHP vs Site PHP

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I have a php that looks something like this:

```
(?i)<(.*?)((?P<QUALIFY>title|))(.*?)>(.*?)(?P<MATCH>(South Beach))(.*?)<\/.*?>
```

Which works as I wish since

- `<title>Bla South Beach</title>`

returns

- QUALIFY: TItle
- MATCH: South Beach

and

- `Bla bla bla South Beach`

returns nothing.

This is when testing on regex101.

However when this is included in web site code on a live site then

- Bla bla bla South Beach

returns

- QUALIFY: TItle
- MATCH: South Beach

Yes I know, don't parse HTML with Regex. Outside of that any ideas? My other tested regexes work fine, perhaps I'm missing something here?

---

Update. On further checking it turns out that we remove `/n` and `/t` before parsing on site. So all of the `<div>` and other `<tags>` get ganged together. Is there a way to change the regex> Basically I am looking to find either `<title>ba bla South Beach</title>` or a div tag such as `<somethinbg "placetitle"=yada yada>bla bla South Beach</>`

---

Update 2 to clarify from the first comment:

http://regex101.com/r/iX4nS4 is the match that is correct in other words what I am looking for.

I did update the title part of the array to be

- `<([^>]*)(title)([^>]*)>`

but that doesn't help either.

I'm basically trying to match either

- `<title>` 
  OR
- `<something somethingTitle><`

followed immediately by a string that contains

- `South Beach`

before the very next `</`

Examples:

- `<title>Beautiful South Beach!</title>`
- `<meta = "locationTitle"><Beautiful South Beach and sunny Florida!</>`

  ---

Update 3:
On further research it turns out to be the very last `.*?` in the regex

- `<\/.*?>`

I did this because since I am not sure what the opening tags might include I wildcarded the closing <> but it is intepreting it as `</ anything at all until the last >`

Comment: Having a hard time understanding your question. Since you said that something `is` working in regex101, could you post a link to that to give a better idea of what you are doing?

Comment: Of course sorry: http://regex101.com/r/iX4nS4 is the match that is correct. On further research as per update it turns out that it is the removal of the line returns as this http://regex101.com/r/lC3oD5 shows. Basically it is my regex, I'm gathering the wildcard at the end before the last </ is in fact going until it finds the match. In fact I am trying to find the match after the first <title> or first <something here somethingTitle><bla bla South Beach and before the very next </

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is overly complex, try this:

```
<(title)>(.*?South Beach.*?)<\/\1>
```

http://regex101.com/r/sF1gN3

---

Alternative version:

```
<(\S*).*?(title).*?>(.*?South Beach.*?)<\/(\1|\2)>
```

http://regex101.com/r/gU7bQ6

Comment: that is similar to what I had originally yet I am trying to account for other title tags besides <title> e.g. <meta bla bla  destinationTitle bla><Bla bla South Beach bla bla</>. The simplicity appreciated for sure but I still am faced with the front tag variability.

Comment: Similar to how I've set up the `South Beach` part, you can place `.*?` on either side of the front tag to accommodate for variability. I'll edit it in for you.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. Curious why if I do \1\3 I don't get 1-3 matches?

Comment: `\N` where `N` is a number, is just a way to backreference a capture group. If the capture group is empty, it may not display anything.